# why does nmap seems to have problems to see my android devices, sometimes it would see them but sometimes not

Tags: wireless, networking, android, nmap

I have noticed that running `nmap 192.168.0.*` would list all the devices connected to my wireless AP except for my Android phones, however if I do `Ping` any of them they are conected im just wondering what is the reason for that to happen.

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu related question, however the very short answer is because the nmap scan and ping are using different protocols. Study the [nmap documents](http://nmap.org/docs.html) to understand how it works.

Comment: @moderators, While there's no denying that this is off-topic in terms Ubuntu-related, this page is up top when you google "android slow respond to nmap or ping", so it *is* quite helpful to the masses (not just to me). Perhaps move it to a place (Serverfault?) where it may prosper, and redirect from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @cremefraiche notes in the comments, Nmap's [host discovery phase](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html) (sometimes called "ping scan") is not the same thing as ICMP Echo Request (as used by the `ping` utility). In some cases (with root permissions against a target in a different subnet) the ICMP echo request is used, but it would never be used against targets on the same AP as the scanner, unless you explicitly use the `--disable-arp-ping` option.

For reasons I'll get to later, I would guess that you are not running this scan with root (`sudo`) privileges. In this case, Nmap's host discovery is implemented by trying to connect to TCP ports 80 and 443; if either of these is rejected or accepted, the host is considered to be "up." If the connections time out (which can happen with a firewalled system), then the host is marked "down."

If you *were* running with root privilege, Nmap would send an ARP request to determine the MAC address of the IP you are targeting. Answering this kind of request is a *requirement* to being connected on an Ethernet or wireless LAN, so it is pretty much guaranteed to work. If you are using `sudo` and still not getting a response, then you should probably file a bug report with the Nmap project (dev@nmap.org).

Answer (score 0):

Well, i thInk that this is not the place for you to ask, but, I will answer you. If you use -Pn it will treat all the hosts as online. Every time that the host is down, i use -Pn. Example:

```
nmap -Pn 192.168.1.*
```

(Sorry for bad English)

Comment: `-Pn` means "skip host discovery" and will result in a full port scan against every address requested, even if nobody is listening. This can slow your scan down considerably.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the explaining, I did not know this =D